# Implementing abmob in Android

Tags: android, admob

I'm using the google tutorial for implementing admob here:

http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html

I am getting some errors in Eclipse when copy and pasting the code into my project (most likely because I am copy and pasting into the wrong spot).

Can anyone tell me where to put all this code? Or tell me what I am doing wrong that is causing me to get errors in Eclipse.

It would be great if someone could copy and paste the code accurately as to how it should be put into the app's activity!

```
package com.soundboard;

import com.soundboard.SoundManager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.ads.*;

public class Soundboard extends Activity {
    private SoundManager mSoundManager;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

That ^^ is what I have and I need to implement this into it:(although notice I did already import the com.google.ads.*;)

```
import com.google.ads.*;

public class BannerExample extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create the adView
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);
    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
  }
}
```

This was the third page of code on the tutorial website (In case someone needed to follow along).  I am pretty sure I implemented the first two snippets of code accurately on the manifest.

I also tried to put it into the main.xml file as well (there is a tutorial given on .xml insertion from the same site) to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add everything in the manifest?

About the code put in your oncreate

```
        AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
    adView.requestFreshAd();
```

and in your main.xml layout file something like this:

```
    <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
/>
```

ofcourse change the location, id etc to your wishes. 
And make sure you have the following in your manifest file

```
    <!-- The application's publisher ID assigned by AdMob -->
<meta-data android:value="yourkeyhere" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />

<!-- AdMobActivity definition -->
<activity android:name="com.admob.android.ads.AdMobActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" />
<!-- Track Market installs -->          
<receiver android:name="com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver"
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: would it be cool if i posted my code somewhere and you inserted it for me...I am just so confused on where to put it...also what do you put in "yourkeyhere" or rather where do you find the info to put there...